Bluetooth is on but not able to discover any device on ubuntu 24.04 lts
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron laptop. However, I am experiencing an issue with the Bluetooth functionality. While Bluetooth is enabled and appears to be active, it is unable to detect or connect to any devices.
Could you please assist me in troubleshooting this issue?
The Output of sudo systemctl status bluetooth
    bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-09-03 22:39:25 IST; 11min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 835 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9339)
     Memory: 3.2M (peak: 3.7M)
        CPU: 129ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─835 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 03 22:41:55 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:41:58 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:42:02 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:42:16 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Sep 03 22:42:19 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:42:21 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:42:24 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:42:27 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:42:29 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>
Sep 03 22:42:31 mp bluetoothd[835]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (>

bluetoothctl: 5.72
Output of sudo dmesg | grep -i 'blue' command
[    4.289816] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.289850] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.289853] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.289858] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.289862] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.289867] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.588867] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    4.604723] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    4.636660] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    4.636664] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    4.654476] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    4.654484] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[    4.654490] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[    6.022437] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.022451] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.022458] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.034274] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   17.393173] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.393189] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.393199] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   18.139718] Modules linked in: rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_ctl_led intel_rapl_msr spi_nor intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mtd x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_intel coretemp btusb(OE) kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi btrtl btbcm snd_hda_codec spi_intel_platform btintel btmtk dell_laptop snd_hda_core rtsx_usb_ms kvm dell_wmi binfmt_misc at24 mei_pxp mei_hdcp spi_intel bluetooth memstick snd_hwdep nouveau dell_smm_hwmon nls_iso8859_1 irqbypass i915 wl(POE) crct10dif_pclmul ecdh_generic polyval_clmulni polyval_generic snd_pcm dell_smbios ghash_clmulni_intel ecc sha256_ssse3 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel drm_gpuvm drm_exec crypto_simd dcdbas cryptd gpu_sched snd_seq rapl drm_ttm_helper drm_buddy ledtrig_audio intel_cstate i2c_i801 snd_seq_device dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof sparse_keymap snd_timer mxm_wmi ttm mei_me cfg80211 i2c_smbus drm_display_helper
[  155.086633] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  155.086635] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[  155.239335] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  157.262616] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  159.886661] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[  159.886670] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  159.985278] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  161.998620] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  178.894656] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  178.894677] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[  178.976664] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  181.006682] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  183.374653] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[  183.374660] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  184.384789] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  186.447688] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  188.494838] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  188.494844] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[  188.631701] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  190.670715] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110

Output of uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb | grep -i 'blue'; sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
inux mp 6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug  2 20:41:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
--
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:0655]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
[    0.110878] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.152136] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    4.654476] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
bluetooth            1028096  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth

Output of lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
> 06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
> BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)     Subsystem: Dell Wireless
> 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]     Kernel driver in use: wl
> -- 07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
>   Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
> [1028:0655]   Kernel driver in use: r8169     Kernel modules: r8169


Investigate $ bluetoothctl --help or just $ bluetoothctl and then help, agent on, scan on, ... - fwiw: i have a pair of cheap BT speakers that requires trickery to get connected. They also swap ID (MAC) occasionally.
